# Highest (existing) number in half precision IEEE 754

Tags: binary, floating-point, ieee-754, ieee

Why is `0 11110 1111111111` and not `0 11111 1111111111` the highest half precision number?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because an exponent field of 11111<sub>2</sub> is reserved for infinities and NaNs. Section 3.4 of the IEEE 754-2008 standard says:

> The range of the encoding’s biased exponent E shall include:
>
> - every integer between 1 and 2<sup>w</sup> − 2, inclusive, to encode normal numbers
> - the reserved value 0 to encode ±0 and subnormal numbers
> - the reserved value 2<sup>w</sup> − 1 to encode ±∞ and NaNs.

Here "w" is the width of the exponent field. This applies not just to the half-precision format, but to all the IEEE 754 binary interchange formats (including the usual single and double precision formats).

In the particular case of the binary16 format, w is 5 and the top 5 bits following the sign bit describe the biased exponent E, and can range from 00000<sub>2</sub> to 11111<sub>2</sub>. The top value in this range, 11111<sub>2</sub>, is used for infinities and NaN values, and the bottom value of 00000<sub>2</sub> is used for zeros and subnormals. The remaining biased exponent values are used for representing finite normal numbers. So the top biased exponent value available for a *finite* number is 2<sup>w</sup> - 2 = 11110<sub>2</sub> rather than 11111<sub>2</sub>.

For this format, the exponent bias is 15, so the bit pattern 0 11110 1111111111 gives an unbiased exponent of 30 - 15 = 15, and represents a value of 1.1111111111<sub>2</sub> × 2<sup>15</sup>, or 65504.

To give another example, the largest binary32 (single-precision) float is represented by bit pattern

> 0 11111110 11111111111111111111111<sub>2</sub>

Comment: Why is `0 11110 1111111111` equal to 65504? If I convert it to decimal I get 31743 and not 65504.

Comment: I also get 65504. Starting from binary 1.1111111111 and shifting the binary point 15 places to the right gives binary 1111111111100000, which is 65504.

Comment: @S.Eberl It looks as though you are treating 11110 1111111111 as a simple binary number, not as a biased exponent and the bits after the binary point in the significand. Please re-read whatever materials you are using to study IEEE floating point, and then look again at the sentence beginning "For this format" in the answer.

Comment: How does 0 11110 1111111111 represent 1.1111111111 × 2^15? Isn't there a zero missing? If I convert it to half precision by shifting the . until I have only one 1 before the point, I'd be getting a 1 somewhere.

Comment: @S.Eberl: The initial `0` gives the sign. The `11110` gives the exponent, which (after removing bias) is 15.  The ten remaining ones: `1111111111` form what IEEE 754 calls the "trailing significand": they represent the *fractional* part of the significand. After including the implicit leading `1` bit, the significand is 1.1111111111_2, and so the whole value is 1.1111111111_2× 2^15.  I'm not sure what you mean about a missing zero.

Comment: The descriptions on the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-precision_floating-point_format) may help.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to me yet. After shifting the . 0 11110 1111111111 becomes 01.1110 1111111111 * 2^14. What happens to the zero in front of the 1?

Comment: Don't include the first six bits in what you're shifting: those are the sign and exponent fields.  You only want to shift the *significand*, which you get from the placing the last ten bits in the original bit string after the point, and an implicit leading 1 before the point.

Comment: But isn't what you call the "significant" actually the fractional part of the number? Why do I have to ignore the exponent and everything?

Comment: @S.Eberl: Sorry, this wasn't a good answer: I totally misunderstood where you were coming from. I don't have the time and resources right now to write a thorough explanation of how the conversion works; maybe someone else does.

Comment: If someone's expiring the same problem or is having the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33461757/half-precision-conversion