# Half precision conversion

Tags: binary, floating-point, ieee-754, ieee

How comes that `0 11110 1111111111` is equal to the half precision format `1.1111111111 * 2^15`? Both should be 65504.

The sign bit here is a 0. The exponent would be 11101 and the fractional part 1111111111. But that doesn't look like `1.1111111111 * 2^15` at all.

Can someone explain that to me?

Comment: Look at that link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33454045/highest-existing-number-in-half-precision-ieee-754/33454736?noredirect=1#comment54709214_33454736

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the layout of your half-precision number:

[image: Number layout]

The exponent's value is 11110<sub>2</sub>, which is 30<sub>10</sub>. Half-precision numbers have exponent [*bias*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponent_bias) of 15<sub>10</sub>, so we need to subtract 15<sub>10</sub> from 30<sub>10</sub> to get the actual exponent of 15<sub>10</sub>.

There is an implicit 1<sub>2</sub> pre-pended to the fraction, so the actual fraction has one extra 1 in front of it. The binary fraction point is located immediately after that implicit 1, making the number look like this:

```
1.1111111111
```

In order to apply the binary exponent of 15<sub>10</sub>, we need to move the fraction point fifteen positions to the right. This produces the number 1111111111100000<sub>2</sub>, which is equal to 65504<sub>10</sub> after the conversion.

Comment: Thanks a million, really! You saved my life. I didn't realize that 0 11110 1111111111 is already in half precision format which means I don't have to convert it into half precision. Thanks!